# Rails: how to tell the difference between leaving an attribute unchanged vs explicitly setting the new value to be the same as the old value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

ActiveRecord `User` has `email` and `email_verified`. If an email changes, it sets `email_verified` to false using:

`before_save :process_new_email, if: :email_changed?`

`process_new_email` is basically just:

```
def process_new_email
   self.email_verified = false
end
```

However, for `user.update(email: email, email_verified: true)`, this also sets `email_verified` to false if `email_verified` was previously `true`.

I.e. this fails:

```
      user = create(:user, email: 'test@example.com', email_verified: true)
      user.update!(email: 'other@example.com', email_verified: true)
      expect(user.email_verified).to eq(true)
```

And this passes:

```
      user = create(:user, email: 'test@example.com', email_verified: true)
      user.update!(email: 'other@example.com')
      expect(user.email_verified).to eq(false)
```

How can I make both test cases pass?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why would you want your fist spec to pass? The e-mails is changing, so the verified flag should be false. The logic of what you're trying to do is not clear. (FYI I didn't downvote it)

Comment: We had a bug where someone wrote `user.update!(email: 'other@example.com', email_verified: true)` and people couldn't update their emails. I think it's reasonable to assume that `email_verified = true` after running that update statement, especially if you're not familiar with Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `email_verified_came_from_user?` method that ActiveRecord creates for you (it creates that method for each attribute).

Check this for example:

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'test@example.com')
user.email_came_from_user? # => false
user.email = 'test@example.com' # setting the same so no change
user.email_came_from_user? # => true
```

So, I would do something like:

```
def process_new_email
  self.email_verified = false unless email_verified_came_from_user?
end
```

Comment: That looks very promising! I can't find any docs on it though, looks like it's intended to be an internal method? So it's kind of like `changed?`, except it's `true` as long as a change was attempted, even if nothing was changed?

Comment: @LeoJiang I can't find docs on this (only the source code), it's a public method so I don't think it's intended to be only used internally, but I'm not sure though.

Comment: I think it's here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/477ec2675d2321eeaa0f5330ab5f3e12b09cb361/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L294 where it's being forwarded to (probably) https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast/attribute_came_from_user%3F

Answer (score 0):

Try revert email_verified if it was changed.

```
before_save :revert_email_verified, if: :email_verified_changed?
before_save :process_new_email, if: :email_changed?

def revert_email_verified
  self.email_verified = email_verified_was
end
```